# Remotely create iPA or archive build

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, ipa

How can I create iPA or Archive build without using xcode.

Schene - User can generate iPA from web app.

I know user can generate iPA using command line , But user should have xcode in his local machine then only he will be able to do it.

But i want to generate iPA remotely , Where user not have xcode.

He will have Git link (where entire project is available)

**Another query**

Currently user can archive or create iPA from local xcode project. I want to generate iPA directly from source code url (git/SVN). Is this possible ?
is it possible to do it without using jenkins or Fastlane

Answer (score 2):

You can use a something like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) to pull from the Git link and compile the project. The easiest way to do this is to combine Jenkins with [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/).

Comment: can i do this with ajax call , Basically i will have a web  page , There i will have button , If user taps on button iPA should be generated.

Comment: I'm not an ajax person so I'm not sure. However, if you have jenkins running on a server, it has its own web page that runs. After you've configured Jenkins, you literally press a button and it generates the IPA.

Comment: Ok my requirment is that if i click on button iPA should be generated , Is there any way i can integrate Jenkins in my web app

Comment: ajax is just an event , In this event i want to genegrate iPA